# Bash commands using smb:// -> No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, mount, samba

I have an smb share that I see in the Files explorer as smb://whitebox.local/photos/
If I try to use commands on this smb share using the smb:// syntax, I get a "No such file or directory" error message:

```
hippo@hippo-camp:~/Desktop$ ls smb://whitebox.local/photos/
ls: cannot access 'smb://whitebox.local/photos/': No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications using GUI frameworks such as Gnome or KDE let you access not only local files, but also various kinds of URL. On the command line, and in GUI applications that don't support URL, you can only access files.

Files don't have to be local files: they can be files on a network share, but that share has to be [mounted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)). (Note in case you're used to Windows: whereas Windows traditionally makes each disk and network share available under a separate drive letter, Unix makes all files accessible from a single root.)

Generally, if a file is available through a URL syntax in a Gnome file manager, you can make it available to all applications by mounting the resource using [gvfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs). You can do that with the [`gio`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gio.1.html) command. (It should be available in your distribution, but it may not be installed by default. On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint… it's in the `libglib2.0-bin` package, which is automatically installed if `ubuntu-desktop` or `gnome` is.)

```
gio mount smb://whitebox.local/
ls -l $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/whitebox.local/photos/
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't fly on a linux (*NIX in general, I guess) box. You might try mounting that on the file system (check `man mount.cifs` or `man mount.smb3`) or try hitting that resource with a proper client like `smbclient`.

Comment: and welcome to SE!